# connection reset in socket file transfer

Tags: java, sockets, file-transfer

i just want to run a sample code  for file transfer using sockets , in eclipse! and the client gives me  this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at Client.main(Client.java:13)
```

i don't think that it is caused by the other side closing the socket!
 here's the code of server and client:

```
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(1000);
        File myFile = new File("s.pdf");

        while (true) {
            Socket sock = servsock.accept();
            byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(myFile));
            bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
            os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            os.flush();
            sock.close();
        }
    }
}


public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1000);
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[1024];
        InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("s.pdf");
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        int bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        bos.write(mybytearray, 0, bytesRead);
        bos.close();
        sock.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not supposed to `throws Exception` from the `main` method. You must handle the exception.

Comment: Is the connection being closed before the file transfer is complete? As you have it, the server closes the connection once the file transfer is complete which would trigger the exception - this seems to be normal behavior. Handling a socket exception is the way to deal with normal disconnections.

Comment: @nhahtdh Untrue. If it wasn't perfectly legal Java for main() to throw an exception, it wouldn't compile. It does. QED.

Comment: "I don't think that it is caused by the other side closing the socket." Why not? It's the usual reason. Not the only one, but the usual one. And where is your *question?*

Comment: thank you! i didn't noticed that the file was transferred! i only have to handle the exception!:))

Comment: @nhahtdh It is perfectly allowable to have a main method that throws an exception. That's how stack traces end up in the command line in console applications.

Comment: @MooshiBlack why are you reading only 1024 bytes where as server can send more bytes than this ?

Comment: @EJP: It's perfectly legal in the language, but it is good practice not to declare `throws Exception` in main. All checked Exception must be handled the latest in main function. This is my whole point when posting that comment.

Comment: @nhahtdh In your opinion. I don't share it. This is sample code, not production software.